# MSVCR110d.dll couldn't be found although exists

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-c++

I have compiled my program with visual studio 2012 in debug version with shared runtime library option, but when I send my app to my friends, they have alert, that MSVCR110d.dll couldn't be found. This is strange, because I attached this file in the app root directory.

What could be the reason?

Comment: I fear the title of your question is wrong: you mean surely "MSVCR110d.dll couldn't be found although exists" ?

Comment: yup, i changed the title

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10406852/1758762 HTH

Comment: But this problem concerns situation, where application is compiled in release mode and it still requires debug version of runtime library. I have compiled my application in debug version. I don't want to force my friends to install redistributable libs. I think static linking is the solution, but I still want to know, what is the reason of my problem.

Comment: Have you read this as well: ...More to the point, the debug version is not redistributable, so it's not as simple as "packaging" it with your executable, or zipping up those DLLs ?

Comment: I didn't notice that. I think this is the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406852/1758762 ,

> The debug version is not redistributable, so it's not as simple as
>   "packaging" it with your executable, or zipping up those DLLs.
>
> Check to be sure that you're compiling all components of your
>   application in "release" mode, and that you're linking the correct
>   version of the CRT and any other libraries you use (e.g., MFC, ATL,
>   etc.).
>
> You will, of course, require msvcr100.dll (note the absence of the d
>   suffix) and some others if they are not already installed. Direct your
>   friends to download the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable (or x64), or
>   include this with your application automatically by building an
>   installer.